# Minecraft Server Portforwarding not working

Tags: minecraft

Ok so me and my friend our trying to make a server and I'v done this before a few years ago but..

I have port forwarded TCP/UDP with my static ip 192.168.1.150 and port 25565

My firewall has been configured to let 25565 through... I have a NetGear Genie with New Wave Communications My IP is: 24.100.150.53

Can anyone help and if you need any more info just comment..

Thanks, abrad1212/Alex

Comment: Does your ISP allow you to forward ports?

Comment: `192.168.1.1500` is not a valid IP address ;)

Comment: Sorry I ment 192.168.1.150

Comment: @Geek1011 Yes because previsouly a few years ago I was running a successful server :D

Comment: OK, I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just covering bases here.

first of all you should check your firewall if inbound connections on ports 25565 are blocked, if your able to connect locally then your machines firewall is not and issue.

Secondly here is a screenshot of the configuration I know works, it allows 192.168.0.52 receive connections on port 27015 and 27005.
[image: Screen Dump]

It would pay to check that the firewall on your router is allowing connections.

If issues still persists putting your machine on to a [DMZ](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1118/~/how-do-i-configure-a-device-to-be-in-the-dmz-on-my-netgear-router%3F) or Demilitarized zone effectively allows all inbound to a selected IP see below (USING A DMZ CAN CAUSE SECURITY ISSUES).
[image: DMZ]

you can check if your ports are open using [this site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytALY.png).(ensure you change the port from 80 to the port you have forwarded for your server)

Asides from the networking side you should check that your server is not posting any error and is bound to the correct IP and port.

And finally if you still having issues have a look at [Portmapper](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) this software allows you to open and close ports using [UPNP](https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper) when your finished.
Personally I find this better because you don't have those ports open all the time only when you trigger it.

[additional instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/122227/how-to-quickly-forward-ports-on-your-router-from-a-desktop-application/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35192/discussion-on-answer-by-mrdeanosupreamo-minecraft-server-portforwarding-not-work).

Comment: Hey go to the chat it says comments are not for extended discussion